# Access key: [ { "Key":"Value"} ] inside of Object that is inside of another Array?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, nested, jsx

I am trying to access the Options key value and get the Name and Value in my jsx but I am unable to use map on field.Options (when I hover over Options there is a question mark next to it).

I have tried field.Options[0].Name , field.Options["Name"], field.map().

I am just confused on how to access those values. An explanation would be appreciated.

[image: Object in Array in a an Array of objects.]

I have an Array[] of Objects{} like below and I am trying to get the "Options" objects values.
{
"Type": "rating",
"Key": "professionalism",
"LabelBranding": "api#professionalism#placeholder",
"Label": "Professionalism:",
"Required": false,
"Options": [
{
"Name": "Smiley",
"Value": "0123456789"
}
]
},

I cant use a (for of ) in JSX. So I am wondering how to access this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you were close there. Have you tried this?

```
{field.Options.map(block => (
  <p key={block.Name}>{block.Value}</p>
))}
```

Since you want to iterate the `field.Options` array.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried and I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". When I hover over "Options" in VSCode It has a question-mark next to it.

Comment: I needed to check if field.Options was undefined before mapping over the object. The first object in the array did not have the "Options" key value in it so it was kicking it out before it got to the second. Thanks for your response @rateLess

Answer (score 0):

This was a case of not checking if the "Options" array was there. The 1st object that was coming back did not have the "Options" key value like the rest of them. So I added a conditional around it and it worked swimmingly.

```
                {field.Options !== undefined
              && field.Options.map((block) => {
                if (block.Value !== undefined || block.Name !== undefined) {
                  return (
                    <ul>
                      <li key={block.Name}>{block.Value}</li>
                      <li key={block.Name}>{block.Name}</li>
                    </ul>
                  );
                }
                return null;
              })
            }
```